# what does IFS='' or IFS= means?

Tags: bash, shell, sh, ifs

IFS is used as word splitting characters but what exactly happens when IFS is null/empty.
For instance , consider the input file abc.txt with contents

```
first line
second line
```

now , if I run

```
IFS='' # or IFS= or assume IFS is null
for word in $(cat abc.txt)
do
 echo ${word}
done
```

Then the output is

```
first line
second line
```

notice , in output , two lines had been shown.
Now , the question is why two lines are showing up instead of one?
If no IFS is being used as word splitting character then I guess the output should be

```
first line second line
```

Shouldn't the output be in a single line only , since \n is also not a IFS at this moment?

Comment: Its correct that it doesn't split at the newline, but why should it just _drop_ the newline? Its part of your `word`.

Comment: *<enter favourite search engine here>* is your friend, make use of it. Your find posts like: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/184863/what-is-the-meaning-of-ifs-n-in-bash-scripting

Comment: You are assuming the loop body executes twice: it doesn't.

Answer (score 5):

You have IFS set but to an empty value.

Assuming you are using a POSIX-compliant shell, if IFS is empty, as per IEEE Std 1003.1, 2004 (minor update to [POSIX.1-2001](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX#POSIX.1-2001_(with_two_TCs))) section [2.6.5 Field Splitting](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_05) says:

> If the value of IFS is null, no field splitting shall be performed.

So you are actually not iterating over the lines, just printing all in one run. If relevant, please note that *unsetting* IFS will have a very different behaviour (making it behave as if it was filled with the defaults, space/tab/newline).

Answer (score 2):

The entire contents of `abc.txt` are assigned to `word` in the first iteration of the loop, including the linefeeds at the end of each line. Those linefeeds are part of the argument to `echo`, which writes them to standard output.

Your loop executes exactly once, with the single call to `echo` writing the two lines read from the file.

(Add `declare -p word` to the body of the loop to see the full value of `word` in the one and only iteration.)